# Python vs Groovy vs Ruby? (based on criteria listed in question)

Tags: python, ruby, scripting, groovy

Considering the criteria listed below, which of Python, Groovy or Ruby would you use?

- *Criteria (Importance out of 10, 10 being most important)*
- Richness of API/libraries available (eg. maths, plotting, networking) (9)
- Ability to embed in desktop (java/c++) applications (8)
- Ease of deployment (8)
- Ability to interface with DLLs/Shared Libraries (7)
- Ability to generate GUIs (7)
- Community/User support (6)
- Portability (6)
- Database manipulation (3)
- Language/Semantics (2)

Comment: I think you missed one criterion: - Familiarity among project team (10)

Comment: Are you excluding jRuby and jython? They really muddy the discussion regarding portability and semantics.

Comment: If Language/Semantics rates only a 2, I'd assume any language could be suggested.

Comment: For small projects, add lua to the list

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think it's going to be difficult to get an objective comparison.  I personally prefer Python.  To address one of your criteria, Python was designed from the start to be an embeddable language.  It has a very rich C API, and the interpreter is modularized to make it easy to call from C.  If Java is your host environment, you should look at Jython, an implementation of Python inside the Java environment (VM and libs).

Answer (score 29):

Having worked with all 3 of them, this is what I can say:

- **Python**

  - has very mature libraries
  - libraries are documented
  - documentation can be accessed from your debugger/shell at runtime through the docstrings
  - you can develop code without an IDE
- **Ruby**

  - has some great libraries ( even though some are badly documented )
  - Ruby's instrospection mechanisms are great. They make writing code pretty easy ( even if documentation is not available )
  - you can develop code without an IDE
- **Groovy**

  - you can benefit from everything Java has to offer
  - syntax is somewhat inspired from Ruby
  - it's hard to write code without an IDE. You have no way to debug stuff from your console ( this is something you can easily do in Python/Ruby ) and the available Groovy plugins have a lot of catching up to do. I wrote some apps using Groovy and as they get bigger I regret not going with Ruby/Python ( debugging would have been WAY more easier ). If you'll only develop from an IDE, Groovy's a cool language.

Comment: How would you say the maturity of Java's libraries compares to that of Python's?

Comment: Usually Java's libraries are of pretty good quality. And since you can use Jython ( to benefit from them while writing Python code ), I'd say you're good either way.

Answer (score 24):

Just to muddy the waters...

Groovy give you access to Java.  Java has an extremely rich set of APIs/Libraries, applications, etc.

Groovy is embeddable, although easiest in Java.

DLLs/Libraries (if you're talking about non-Groovy/Java) may be somewhat problematic, although there are ways and some APIs to help.

I've done some Python programming, but being more familiar with Java, Groovy comes a lot easier to me.

Answer (score 10):

Groovy? I'm just picking it up; try this (inside the groovyconsole):

```
File.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
    System.out.print ("Call to $name intercepted...");
    File.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(delegate, args);
}

new File("c:/temp").eachFile{
    if (it.isFile()) println it.canonicalPath
}
```

The first code is AOP. All calls to any method of File object will be intercepted. No additional tools required. This is executed against existing Java class dynamically.

In the second block, you remove the 'f' closure parameter. Being just one parameter, it defaults to the built in "it" variable available to the closure context.

Here is what you get:

"Call to isFile intercepted...C:\temp\img.jpg"

etc.

Answer (score 8):

try Groovy .. it has all features that you need there. You can use existing java lib without any modification on its classes. 
basically .. groovy is java++, it is more dynamic and fun to learn (just like ruby)

I dont like ruby or python syntax so I will put them behind. Groovy is just like C/C++ syntax so I like him lol :)

Answer (score 7):

Python has all nine criteria.  It scores a 56.

I'm sure Ruby has everything Python has.  It seems to have fewer libraries.  So it scores a 51.

I don't know if Groovy has every feature.

Since Python is 56 and Ruby is a 51, Python just barely edges out Ruby.

However, I think this kind of decision can still boil down to some subjective issues outside these nine criteria.

Comment: With all respect, I don't think Ruby has the same amount of libraries as Python has, not to mention Groovy. If I e.g. take Ubuntu packages (including multiverse, which means basically it's Debian packages), there 920 package names with Python and 464 with Ruby. Groovy has no 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Update: I looked at Rubyforge and PyPI and it it seems to support this estimate that Python has almost twice as more libraries than Ruby.

Comment: Update two years later: There are more RubyGems listed than PyPI packages. But it's not a pissing contest. Both Ruby and Python are mature enough to have excellent libraries for just about anything you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

From your critera, I'd pick JRuby:

- Richness of API/libraries available (eg. maths, plotting, networking) (9)

Everything the JVM has access to, which is a *lot*

- Ability to embed in desktop (java/c++) applications (8)

Excellent [Monkeybars](http://monkeybars.rubyforge.org) framework, which lets you design a swing GUI in your GUI designer, and then wire it up using clean ruby code

- Ease of deployment (8)

[Rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org) can package your app as an executable jar

- Ability to interface with DLLs/Shared Libraries (7)

Java shared libraries easily, C ones via [jna + libffi](http://blog.headius.com/2007/09/java-native-access-jruby-true-posix.html)

- Ability to generate GUIs (7)

Swing just works. Not sure how easy it is to use QtJambi, but it's definitely possible.

- Community/User support (6)

Lots. Ruby has an excellent community.

- Portability (6)

Everywhere the JVM works

- Database manipulation (3)

All the ruby database libraries *and* all the java ones

- Language/Semantics (2)

Here's where ruby takes the definite lead over groovy and python. The language has had some really beautiful design decisions taken early on, which shows up in the consistency and power of the standard library. [Blocks](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/19/blocks-rock), in particular, make it a joy to use.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of adding-up-scores-by-features is not a good way to choose a programming language. You'd be better off choosing whichever you know the best. If you don't know any of them, try them out for a little while. If you have a really specific project in mind, then maybe some programming languages would be better, but if you just have general preferences you will never come to a consensus.

That said, Python is pretty flexible, it's the most popular on your list so the easiest to solve whatever sorts of problems you have by searching, so I'd recommend Python.

Answer (score 2):

Perl? Yikes.

As someone has observed Perl is like a big explosion in a punctuation factory. It's terseness is **not** an advantage if the resultant code is not self documenting.

Have used Groovy for some utility tasks, easy to get going. Full access to Java libraries, plus some cool addtions to it, like listing the files in a directory using a closure:

```
// process all files printing out full name (. and .. auto excluded)

new File(basedir).eachFile{ f->

    if (f.isFile()) println f.canonicalPath
}
```

Comment: "perl is too much punctuation/line noise" # the number 1 hallmark of somebody whos not tried it.

Comment: @Kent Fredric: Mostly agreed, though I would say "learned" as opposed to "tried".  It does take some time, but then so does any language.  For some reason a lot of people seem to consider any language that doesn't use the same conventions as one they already know to be inferior.  If anything, it would seem logical that punctuation is *easier* to remember, since (perhaps ironically) once you get how it's used, there's usually only one mapping that makes sense, unlike languages that use words (which have synonyms) for the same concepts.

Comment: The problem while doing "utility tasks" with Groovy is that Java don't have any low level methods like chmod, chown, fork, etc.

Comment: "chown tmp/foo".execute ( )  ? - http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not on your list, but at least look at perl.

- Richness of Api/Libraries to sink a ship.
- Runs on more systems than most people realise exists.
- Works well with Binary libraries.
- Has a huge community.
- Portability, See above.
- Database manipulation: more ways to do it. ( Pick your favorite module )
- And one of the most expressive/terse languages around.

Comment: A downside of perl for those unfamiliar with it is the lack of organization of its plethora of modules.  There is, at least to my knowledge, no convenient way to find the most suitable of a number of available modules for a particular task.  The fact that there are so many options is wonderful, but there should be a better way to sift through it all for modules that are considered production-ready and/or commonly used and/or full-featured and/or lightweight and/or compatible with various perl releases (for example, some newer versions of modules only support perl 5.10).

Comment: @intuited Perl isn't my favorite language, but you've got it completely backwards. Perl is the one language I know where it's easiest to find suitable modules. CPAN (http://search.cpan.org/) has lots of ways to determine suitability: automated tests performed on new submissions on many OS platforms; ratings and comments; sane naming and namespace conventions, etc. CPAN is better organized than RubyGems and PyPI.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: It seems like the cpan site functionality could use some work.  I was until just now unaware of the [dlsip](http://search.cpan.org/dlsip) rating system that is displayed when you browse through categories, because it's not displayed when you do text searches, which is how I usually do things.  This is a tremendously useful dataset, but I don't understand why it's not consistently displayed.  Actually that seems to be the only context in which it *is* displayed — it doesn't even show up when you go to the module's page.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: I'm also still looking for the "advanced search" page that will let me search for modules meeting certain criteria from the dlsip, user ratings, version number, etc. Does this exist somewhere?  __________  Granted, PyPI doesn't have this sort of functionality either, although the "Score" column in PyPI search results is at least vaguely useful. The tendency for Python module development to converge, in many cases into the standard library, makes it somewhat less important. It's also helpful that the "Production Status" of a module is usually given on that module's page.

Comment: Items that have been rated tend to come up higher precedence, and the score of their rating affects the order of rated items. =)