# Why are Ruby and Python more suited for programming outside an IDE than Groovy?

Tags: python, ruby, groovy, language-comparisons

This is mainly in reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257730/python-vs-groovy-vs-ruby-based-on-criteria-listed-in-question/1401616#1401616) in "[Python vs Groovy vs Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257730/python-vs-groovy-vs-ruby-based-on-criteria-listed-in-question)"

What makes Python and Ruby easier to develop outside an IDE?

The link also mentions debugging in the console. What is meant by that exactly?

Comment: Languages that are so cumbersome to develop in as to virtually require an IDE to do without pain and suffering are inherently flawed, and the IDE just a band-aide atop those flaws.  Python, Perl, and Ruby are all straightforward languages that don’t need complicated gizmos to work around painful design bugs.

Comment: @tchrist: Do you have to maintain existing apps, or do you only develop new apps?

Comment: @Andrew, for the most part I develop new programs, but that still requires dealing with other people’s code: libraries and stuff. I do biomedical textmining, so sometimes have to hold my nose and dirty myself with Java. But not too much: I leave the UIMA bits and such to others. But there is a lot of Perl support for biomed areas, and a fair bit for NLP. I'm still trying to find a stemmer that works well on biomed text. Snowball is better than Porter (I *think*), but both have issues with all the classical morphology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the assertion that groovy is harder to develop with outside of an IDE.  I've done serious python and groovy development, and a little bit of ruby, mostly without an IDE.

While there isn't a `pdb` style debugger, there's a console: groovysh is a non-GUI console, command line app, and groovyConsole is a GUI with simple syntax highlighting and editing.  The rails and TDD philosophies emphasize development with tests rather than debuggers, and I find I rarely, if ever, feel the need to use a full-on debugger if I've got good test coverage.  Whether this matters to you really depends on your own style of development.

Groovy simplifies the whole `jar`/`classpath` mess.  While you can still set the classpath if you want, it's much easier to let groovy manage it entirely.  Groovy automatically includes jars in `$GROOVY_HOME/lib` and  `~/.groovy/lib` in the classpath.  Installing a library is simply copying it there.  Better than that, with `@Grab`, you can declare your dependencies right at the top of your script, and groovy will automatically download the version you specify, and recursively get all of *its* dependencies and set up the proper classpath and classloaders; it can even manage two libraries that depend different versions of the same jar.  Grails also has declarative dependencies.

The groovy language itself is just as concise and flexible as either ruby or python.  While you *can* write it like full-blown Java, groovy can be written to look very similar to ruby.

One valid complaint against groovy vs python and ruby is that the startup time of the JVM is still noticeably worse.

Comment: Re: JVM startup time - In my opinion, that's more a result of the JVM being more focused on longer-running applications (both server and desktop) than on scripts, which is where Python and Ruby have much more of a focus.

Answer (score 5):

Python and Ruby are easier to develop outside of an IDE than most of the JVM languages in general because they require less "overhead."  I will speak primarily about Python, because that's my primary language.

In general, a Python installation has a single source for libraries (unless you're using `virtualenv`), and the whole project lives on the filesystem.  There is no need to worry about `.jar` or `.class` files -- everything is compiled at runtime, and the `.py` files are your distributables.

Furthermore, Python is more concise than Java, and Groovy inherits a lot of Java's syntax (although it abstracts some things away).  IDEs help to deal with boilerplate, making it less work for the programmer -- but languages without so much boilerplate don't require that help.

Comment: good point about the libraries. I'm not sure If I agree about conciseness of the languages themselves though.

Comment: You start by saying that JVM languages have more "overhead", but then neglect to support that claim, unless you mean only "where libraries live" when you talk about overhead. Also, one of Groovy's main goals is to eliminate the typical Java boilerplate, which includes concise code. It's true that Groovy is happy to run most Java as-is, but that's not Groovy, that's just Java running on the Groovy compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Also for example Ruby on Rails includes some things that would otherwise be handled by IDEs like generators and console.

Comment: Grails also includes lots of CLI-friendly tooling, including a CLI-based shell explicitly for facilitating creating Grails apps.